# How to send facefook notification to the users on a blog post created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a site similar to blog. In that I would like to add a facebook notification feature.
For example, if I created one article it should send a notification to the subscribed facebook users.

I have done facebook share. But I don't know about this.

Note: I'm using asp.net and c# for the web development.

Is this possible. if possible, can someone say a way to achieve it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications/ - Use the notification API for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all You will need to create a facebook application and add your web page as a "Web Page with Facebook login": You can find this setting in application settings. After you will need to log in your blog users via facebook and ask for some basic permissions (No special permission needed for sending notifications.) And after all these steps you will be able to send notifications to your users. Here are some resources that might help you. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/gettingstarted/ 
[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/#cs) is the C# SDK resource.